# Goto in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, goto

I was looking through an error message that MATLAB gave me when I saw the command *opentoline*. After opening its help doc:

> **opentoline** Open to specified line in function file in Editor.

Doesn't this serve the same purpose as goto as it can take you to the specific line number of any program?

Comment: 'goto' is evil.

Comment: There's no goto in MATLAB

Comment: You know what Dijkstra [thought about `goto`](https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/rerg/arvo/courses/kvse/uebungen/Dijkstra_Goto.pdf), right? :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`opentoline` will open the file in Matlab's editor. That's handy if a routine indicates a problem in a specific file/line. Then it can jump (or offer a link) to this location and the user sees the file/line.

`goto` is only for execution, it jumps to the position on execution and will continue executing from the goto target. The editor is not involved in this case. BTW, there is no built-in goto statement in Matlab, but functions called goto from third parties. I wouldn't use them anyway.

Comment: If the user really wanted to, he/she could use `opentoline` and then use what the function returns as an argument to `eval`, right? I understand your larger point though. And yes, goto is evil.

Comment: No, that won't work. All opentoline will do, is open the editor and show the file at the given line. You cannot get the content of the line to eval it. Its just a convenience function for debugging / indicating problems.

Comment: Oh I see it doesn't return anything. Alright thanks.